# Multilevel sort multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

Guys, help me with array sorting.

I have an array:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [pos] => 1
            [team_name] => Team1
            [tours] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [tour_id] => 0
                            [tour_total] => 30
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [tour_id] => 1
                            [tour_total] => 31
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [tour_id] => 2
                            [tour_total] => 29
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [tour_id] => 3
                            [tour_total] => 0
                        )

                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [tour_id] => 4
                            [tour_total] => 0
                        )

                    [5] => Array
                        (
                            [tour_id] => 5
                            [tour_total] => 0
                        )

                    [6] => Array
                        (
                            [tour_id] => 6
                            [tour_total] => 0
                        )

                    [7] => Array
                        (
                            [tour_id] => 7
                            [tour_total] => 0
                        )

                )

            [total] => 90
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [pos] => 2
            [team_name] => Team2
            [tours] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [tour_id] => 0
                            [tour_total] => 30
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [tour_id] => 1
                            [tour_total] => 30
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [tour_id] => 2
                            [tour_total] => 30
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [tour_id] => 3
                            [tour_total] => 0
                        )

                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [tour_id] => 4
                            [tour_total] => 0
                        )

                    [5] => Array
                        (
                            [tour_id] => 5
                            [tour_total] => 0
                        )

                    [6] => Array
                        (
                            [tour_id] => 6
                            [tour_total] => 0
                        )

                    [7] => Array
                        (
                            [tour_id] => 7
                            [tour_total] => 0
                        )

                )

            [total] => 90
        )

)
```

this array contains teams result by tours.

I need sort this array by "total" value. If the values of neighboring teams are equal, then sort by the value of round 8 (tour_id = 7). If the values are equal here, then sort by tour value 7 (tour_id = 6). And so on.

Comment: Does it help `array_multisort ` function: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use `usort()` function for this purpose. If you are using PHP7 or above you can use the below code

```
  usort($array, function($a, $b) {
    return $a[tour_total] <=> $b[tour_total];
  });
```

or for 5.3 and greater

```
  usort($array, function($a, $b) {
    return $a['tour_total'] - $b['tour_total'];
  });
```

Or you can use `array_multisort` like below

```
array_multisort(array_map(function($element) {
      return $element['order'];
  }, $array), SORT_ASC, $array);

print_r($array);
```